# Commands functions available when a reference is available in the VB for applications reference list in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am a hacker with very little training.  I have discovered that there are these things that might be called Microsoft Automation Objects that software developers make available to VB through for example the list of references found when you use VB interface in Excel.  Specifically if I start Excel select the Developer tab, select Visual Basic and then from Tools Select References I get a select box that has a large number of dlls listed.

I found a list of functions that were 'exposed' for one of the listed references.  It was really neat and I could make excel interact with the program itself.

So my question - is there a standard way to determine what 'functions' are exposed by a particular reference listing?

If I am confusing, sorry, let me make an analogy

I use Python and I can find out the things that are available to act on a particular object by typing

```
dir(object)
```

Is there something analogous for VB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select libraries in the Object Browser (code window) and you can set a Watch and step through code. Quite a lot of stuff is listed with Intellisense. BTW in Excel etc, it is VBA.

Comment: thank you very much.  It is really cool I want to stay up all night and test every listed function.  Okay I know.

Comment: It is a fun, but sadly, you cannot use a lot of the libraries in real-world solutions.

Comment: If you are enjoying libraries, you might like APIs ( http://allapi.mentalis.org/ ) You can do a lot more damage with APIs, including crashing your computer in very uncomfortable ways, when what you were doing looked perfectly harmless.

Comment: That sounds like even more fun.